# CardDeck Function flip() for GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm stuck on this flip() function have to create. The flipper_app initializes with three cards in a deck showing the back side. We define that card.display('back') from CardLabel.py where card images are processed in that py file.  Each time flip function(button) is pressed, the card flips to the front side. Press it again, then second card showing front. Third press you have all the cards showing front. The fourth click should remove the first card from the deck, then second, then third until all the cards are gone.

I can't seem to implement these orders in just one function.  I can only seem to flip them all, instead of flipping them one by one.  How can I create a method that does the above?

Here's the code:

```
%gui tk
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
from CardLabel import CardLabel as CardLabel

flipper_app = tk.Tk()
CardLabel.load_images()

label = CardLabel(flipper_app)
label.grid(row=0, column = 0)
label.display('back')

label_2 = CardLabel(flipper_app)
label_2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
label_2.display('back')

label_3 = CardLabel(flipper_app)
label_3.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
label_3.display('back')

def flip():
    labels = [label, label_2, label_3]

    labels[0].display('front', randint(0,51))
    flipper_app.update_idletasks()

flip_button = tk.Button(flipper_app, text='Flip', command= flip) 
flip_button.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, pady = 20)
```